How to optimze datetime query with intersections?
I'm writing a Django application, which involves dealing with datetimes, Appointments which have a starting time (appointment.date_time) and a related service, with its own duration (appointment.service.duration), and TimeSlots, which are basically the hours for every day of the week on which a medic is available to work.
I wanted to get the medic's "free times", which the available places "where" I can add more appointments.
For example:
I have a timeslot on monday: 09:00-12:00. I have an existing appointment, from 10:30-11:00.
This view should ideally return the free times:
09:00-09:30, 09:30-10:00, 10:00-10:30, 11:00-11:30, 11:30-12:00.
(I know this sounds similar to Interval Scheduling, but I'm not sure it exactly matches what I want).
I don't necessarily want the most optimal placing of free times. There are lots of edge cases, which might or might not be handled/worsened with design decisions, such as appointments over two days, invalid appointments, appointments of varying duration.
The question: Is there a way to optimize this code, emphasizing on reducing database load?
Since I will run this on prod, and I can just make the users choose the appointment starting time (which lets them decide what to do on certain edge cases), I would like to prioritize being effective.
Or perhaps this is all a matter of premature optimization, I'm not sure...
My main concern is that I'm calling filter() too much.
Note that appointments have been set up to be passed on ascending date_time order by default.
The following code works (at least for now):
# TODO: Refactor this function and make it more efficient, by avoiding use of filter.
# (specially inside of for loop).
# Idea: the same way I use the time slots to define limits for searching, I can get all appointments 
# and define their starting and ending times as limits.
@require_GET
def get_next_free_times(request):
    username = request.GET.get('medic_id')
    start_str = request.GET.get('start_date')
    start_time_str = request.GET.get('start_time')
    service_duration = time_string_to_seconds(request.GET.get('duration'))

    try:
        start = datetime.strptime(start_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
        end = start + timedelta(days = 1)

        # This variable is used to fix the very rare edge case where an appointment occurs during more than one day
        # If this happens, the value of this variable is updated, and is then compared (using max) with the query_min value.
        mult_day_app_start_time = start

        available_slots = []

        time_slots = TimeSlots.objects.get(medic__user__username=username).slots

        all_appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(
                medic__user__username=username,
        )

        # Keep querying until we find valid time slots from 4 different days
        days_counter = 0
        while days_counter < 4:
            # Get slots for day of the week
            day_slots = time_slots.get(day_mapping[start.weekday()])

            # If there are no available slots today, check next day
            if day_slots == None:
                start = end
                end = start + timedelta(days=1)
                continue
            
            # Now, we can limit the range of appointments queried by using the time slots.
            # We want to calculate 'service_duration' length time slots, between start and end.
            added_appointments_today = False

            for slot in day_slots:
                slot_start = datetime.strptime(slot['start_time'], '%H:%M').time()
                slot_end = datetime.strptime(slot['end_time'], '%H:%M').time()

                query_min = datetime.combine(start.date(), slot_start)
                query_max = datetime.combine(start.date(), slot_end) + timedelta(minutes=1)

                # Query appointments in current time slot.
                appointments = all_appointments.filter(
                    date_time__range=(query_min, query_max)
                )

                current_start = max(round_time_to_duration(query_min, service_duration), mult_day_app_start_time)
                current_end = current_start + timedelta(seconds=service_duration)
                
                # While our current (possible) appointment ends before the time slot's end...
                while current_end <= query_max:
                    in_range_appointments = appointments.filter(
                        date_time__range=(current_start, current_end)
                    )

                    # If there aren't any intersecting appointments, or if the first appointment from
                    # the range starts where our current one would end...
                    if not in_range_appointments:
                        add_slot(available_slots, current_start, current_end)
                        added_appointments_today = True

                        # If we added an appointment this way, the next start is our current end, or
                        # in other words, we just add the service's duration.
                        current_start += timedelta(seconds=service_duration)
                        current_end = current_start + timedelta(seconds=service_duration)

                    # If we reached this point, it means there was an appointment in the range current_start, current_end.
                    else:
                        in_range_appointment = in_range_appointments[0] # Appointments are ordered, so this works

                        app_start_time = in_range_appointment.date_time
                        app_end_time = in_range_appointment.date_time + in_range_appointment.medical_service.duration

                        # If we start where it ends or we end where it starts, we can add our new appointment
                        # It doesn't matter if they intersect at the ends, it's normal to see something like:
                        # "Appointment 9:00-9:30" and then "Appointment 9:30-10:00"
                        if current_start == app_end_time or current_end == app_start_time:
                            add_slot(available_slots, current_start, current_end)
                            added_appointments_today = True

                        current_start = round_time_to_duration(app_end_time, service_duration)
                        current_end = current_start + timedelta(seconds=service_duration)

                        if (app_start_time.day != app_end_time.day):
                            mult_day_app_start_time = current_start

                        # If our appointment could occur during two different days (unlikely, but I should take into account edge cases)
                        # We fetch the next day's timeslots, and see if it's possible to add a slot.
                        if (current_start.day != current_end.day):
                            next_day_slots = time_slots.get(day_mapping[(query_max.weekday() + 1) % 7])

                            if next_day_slots == None:
                                continue
                            
                            # Since slots are sorted, this works
                            day_slot = next_day_slots[0]

                            day_slot_start = datetime.strptime(day_slot['start_time'], '%H:%M').time()
                            day_slot_end = datetime.strptime(day_slot['end_time'], '%H:%M').time()

                            if (day_slot_start != time(0, 0) or current_end.time() > day_slot_end):
                                continue

                            add_slot(available_slots, current_start, current_end)
                            added_appointments_today = True

                            current_start += timedelta(seconds=service_duration)
                            current_end = current_start + timedelta(seconds=service_duration)

            if added_appointments_today:
                days_counter += 1
                added_appointments_today = False

            # Move range to the next day
            start = end
            end = start + timedelta(days=1)

        # Finally, get rid of appointments which are before the initial starting datetime 
        # (the way this code works makes it possible to select those timeslots as valid)
        if start_time_str != 'none':
            start = datetime.strptime(start_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
            start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time_str, "%H:%M").time()

            start_datetime = datetime.combine(start, start_time)

            for i in range(len(available_slots)):
                slot = available_slots[i]
                slot_start = datetime.strptime(slot['start_time'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

                if slot_start >= start_datetime:
                    break
                
            available_slots = available_slots[i:]
        
        return JsonResponse({'available_slots': json.dumps(available_slots)})

    except (TimeSlots.DoesNotExist, Appointment.DoesNotExist):
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Medic or related data not found.'}, status=404)
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)

In case you want the other models:
class MedicalService(models.Model):
    medic = models.ForeignKey(Professional, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Práctica')
    duration = models.DurationField(default=datetime.timedelta(minutes=30), verbose_name='Duración')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TimeSlots(models.Model):
    DAYS_OF_WEEK = (
        ('sunday', 'Sunday'),
        ('monday', 'Monday'),
        ('tuesday', 'Tuesday'),
        ('wednesday', 'Wednesday'),
        ('thursday', 'Thursday'),
        ('friday', 'Friday'),
        ('saturday', 'Saturday'),
    )

    medic = models.ForeignKey(Professional, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slots = models.JSONField(default=dict)

    def clean(self):
        """
        Validate time slots to ensure they are ordered and do not collide.
        Raises ValidationError if any slots are invalid.
        """
        for day, slots in self.slots.items():
            slots.sort(key=lambda slot: slot['start_time'])

            for i in range(1, len(slots)):
                if slots[i - 1]['end_time'] > slots[i]['start_time']:
                    raise ValidationError(f"Time slots for {day.capitalize()} are not ordered or collide.")

    def add_time_slot(self, day_of_week, start_time, end_time):
        day_of_week = day_of_week.lower()
        if day_of_week not in self.slots:
            self.slots[day_of_week] = []

        self.slots[day_of_week].append({
            'start_time': start_time.strftime('%H:%M'),
            'end_time': end_time.strftime('%H:%M')
        })
        self.slots[day_of_week].sort(key=lambda slot: slot['start_time'])
        self.save()

    def update_time_slot(self, day_of_week, index, start_time, end_time):
        day_of_week = day_of_week.lower()
        if day_of_week in self.slots and 0 <= index < len(self.slots[day_of_week]):
            self.slots[day_of_week][index] = {
                'start_time': start_time.strftime('%H:%M'),
                'end_time': end_time.strftime('%H:%M')
            }
            self.slots[day_of_week].sort(key=lambda slot: slot['start_time'])
            self.save()

    def delete_time_slot(self, day_of_week, index):
        day_of_week = day_of_week.lower()
        if day_of_week in self.slots and 0 <= index < len(self.slots[day_of_week]):
            del self.slots[day_of_week][index]
            self.save()

    def get_available_days(self):
        all_days = [day[0] for day in self.DAYS_OF_WEEK]
        scheduled_days = self.slots.keys()
        availability = [day in scheduled_days for day in all_days]
        return availability

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Time slots for {self.medic}: {self.slots}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Available Time Slots'


# ----
class AppointmentManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        request = CrequestMiddleware.get_request()

        if request is None:
            return super().get_queryset().none()
        try:
            return super().get_queryset().filter(enabled=True)
        except Exception as err:
            print(f'Error while querying appointments: {err}')
            super().get_queryset().none()


class Appointment(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Paciente')
    medic = models.ForeignKey(Professional, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Medico')
    medical_service = models.ForeignKey(MedicalService, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Práctica')
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha')
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Notas')
    notify = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Notificar')
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Habilitado")
    
    objects = AppointmentManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Turno para {self.patient} con {self.medic} en {self.date_time}"
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_time']

This is a mess, I know. This was my first attempt at getting something decent. I tried other approaches, like the one on the top comment, but found no success.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time and attention.
